# Hibernate DB Insert but the primary key is an auto increased ID

Tags: database, hibernate, insert

My table's primary key is an auto increased ID

```
TranslationID  | TranslationKeyID | Language | Text
...            | ...              | ...      | ...
45             | R45_NAME_DE      | DE       | Text1
46             | R45_INST_EN      | EN       | Text2
47             | ...              | ...      | ...
```

I want to do Inserts into this table using hibernate.
My approach is to get the object from the DB using the TranslationKeyID
And then check wether the object is null or not to see if the translation already exists

```
HBTranslation hbTlForNameDE = getTranslation(session, "DE", route.getNameKey());
if (hbTlForNameDE == null) {
    hbTlForNameDE = new HBTranslation();
    //how do I set an automatically ongoing ID?
    hbTlForNameDE.setTranslationId(/* ?? */);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The id will be set when calling `entityManager.persist(...)` for that entity. You can read more about this topic here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing